# Popup not closing from parent window?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a problem with closing a pop window. My problem is unique in kind if I click Logout from the parent, it closes all the windows, but when I log out from a child, then I am logging out from Parent, so it does not close the other child windows that are open.

When I am logging out from a child and then I am logging out from a parent, I checked in console and it is not going inside the if block.

I am opening all the pop-ups like this -

```
function openpop1() {
    sessionId = getURLParameters('requestID');
    userName = getURLParameters('userName');
    userId = getURLParameters('userId');
    lvalue = getURLParameters('lValue');
    lver = getURLParameters('lVer');
    window.name = "parent";
    var intWidth = screen.width - 10; //Adjust for the end of screen 
    var intHeight = screen.height - 80; //Adjust for the Icon Bar at the bottom of the window.
    var strWinProp = " toolbar=no"         //Back, Forward, etc...
                   + ",location=no"      //URL field
                   + ",directories=no"   //"What's New", etc...
                   + ",status=yes"       //Status Bar at bottom of window.
                   + ",menubar=no"       //Menubar at top of window.
                   + ",resizable=yes"     //Allow resizing by dragging.
                   + ",scrollbars=yes"   //Displays scrollbars is document is larger than window.
                   + ",titlebar=yes"     //Enable/Disable titlebar resize capability.
                   + ",width="+intWidth    //Standard 640,800/788, 800/788
                   + ",height="+intHeight  //Standard 480,600/541, 600/566               
                   + ",top=0"              //Offset of windows top edge from screen.
                   + ",left=0"             //Offset of windows left edge from screen.
                   + "";  
     awin = window.open(aUrl + userName + "&requestID=" + sessionId
            + "&userId=" + userId + "&lValue=" + lvalue + "&lVer=" + lver,'_blank',strWinProp);
}
function openpop2() {
    sessionId = getURLParameters('requestID');
    userName = getURLParameters('userName');
    userId = getURLParameters('userId');
    lvalue = getURLParameters('lValue');
    lver = getURLParameters('lVer');
    window.name = "parent";
    var intWidth = screen.width - 10; //Adjust for the end of screen 
    var intHeight = screen.height - 80; //Adjust for the Icon Bar at the bottom of the window.
    var strWinProp = " toolbar=no"         //Back, Forward, etc...
                   + ",location=no"      //URL field
                   + ",directories=no"   //"What's New", etc...
                   + ",status=yes"       //Status Bar at bottom of window.
                   + ",menubar=no"       //Menubar at top of window.
                   + ",resizable=yes"     //Allow resizing by dragging.
                   + ",scrollbars=yes"   //Displays scrollbars is document is larger than window.
                   + ",titlebar=yes"     //Enable/Disable titlebar resize capability.
                   + ",width="+intWidth    //Standard 640,800/788, 800/788
                   + ",height="+intHeight  //Standard 480,600/541, 600/566               
                   + ",top=0"              //Offset of windows top edge from screen.
                   + ",left=0"             //Offset of windows left edge from screen.
                   + "";  
     bwin = window.open(bUrl + userName + "&requestID=" + sessionId + "&userId="
            + userId + "&lValue=" + lvalue + "&lVer=" + lver,'_blank',strWinProp);
}
```

And while log out I am calling

```
function onLogout() {
    if (awin && !awin.closed) {
        awin.close();
    }
    if (bwin && !bwin.closed) {
        bwin.close();
    }       

    sessionId = getURLParameters('requestID');
    var rcvReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
    rcvReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rcvReq.readyState == 4 || rcvReq.readyState == 0) {
            var data = rcvReq.status;
        }
    }
    rcvReq.open("GET", logoutUrl +sessionId, true);
    rcvReq.send(null);
    window.location = loginPageUrl;
}
```

Now my problem is why is it not going inside the if block when I am logging out from the child and then the parent. I checked this by adding a breakpoint to these lines.

```
 if (awin && !awin.closed) {
        awin.close();
    }
    if (bwin && !bwin.closed) {
        bwin.close();
    }
```

I also checked whenever I am closing one pop-up the value of the both awin and bwin is getting set to undefined.

But why it happening. Somebody can help me on this?

EDIT :
Is this because if I am logging out I am setting a modal window on main page for user to tell the session is time out.

The code for that is here-

```
if (responseBodyFull == "Invalid Session Id passed") {
                            console.log("Invalid Session");
                            showModalBoxForInvalidSessionInfo();
                           }
```

and the function is defined like this -

```
function showModalBoxForInvalidSessionInfo(){
    $("#modelView").dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        modal : true,
        buttons : [ {
            text : "OK",
            icons : {
                primary : "ui-icon-heart"
            },
            click : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }]
    });
    $("#modelView" ).dialog("open");
    $("#modelView").text("Session Timed Out. Please login again to access the Dashboard");
}
```

But anyway when we do console.log it is coming to the if part. So, I guess this should not be a problem.

Comment: Are `awin` or `bwin` set anywhere else? Is the `onLogout` code running in the same window as the original calls to `window.open`?

Comment: so the problem is that you need to close child windows, and doing it from the child popup don't work right?  have you tried calling `window.parent.onLogout()` ? to execute parent window script from childs?

Comment: @ChrisLear no they haven't defined anywhere else...yes onLogout is running on the same window.

Comment: I am able to close child window when I am calling logout from main window but when I am logging out from one child window which will close the child and foucs will be on main window. Now if I hit logout it will not close other child window...which it was doing previously when logout was hit directly from main window

Comment: @ChrisLear please check I have updated question

Comment: I created a minimal example, with a page that creates two popups, setting them to global `awin` and `bwin` variables. It is then possible to call a method in the parent from one of the popups, which closes both the popups. So I conclude that the problem with your code is in a part that isn't shown in the question.

Comment: @ChrisLear but this is the whole code to close the window. There is nothing except this on this part. I pasted the whole open window and close window code...even I am able to close both the popup from parent but when I am closing one popup first parent is not able to close the other child popup